# Python Twisted returning large but unknown amount of data on API

Tags: python, twisted

I am working on a Python application that will return a json response containing a list of files from a filtered list.  The number of characters in total in the response could be very large depending on the filter (possibly over 5000) so during tests I get multiple dataReceived()'s.

Is there a way to get how big in total the response is so if it ends up over multiple calls I know when I have received a complete message?

The data format is:

```
{
    "files":
    [
       {
           "name": "/etc/passwd",
           "size": 1234
       }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say but I infer that you're using `twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol` directly.  This is the most directly TCP access Twisted gives you.  TCP has no message framing like the kind you're asking about.  If you want message framing, you have to pick a higher-level protocol that offers it (correct solution) or build it yourself (no reason to do this >99% of the time).

Twisted has many higher-level protocols for you to pick from.  I suggest taking a look at Twisted Web and HTTP.